# A question about material implication

Tags: logic

I have a question about reading material implications. I know this read as "if p then q".

like: if the moon is made of green cheese then the earth is round. but I can't read it in this sentence:

> F(x) ≡ |x| → M. that is: F(x) is true if and only if the logical sentence that corresponds to the number x implies M.

or when:

> the sentence L says: this logical sentence implies M.

This is about Löb’s Paradox and I can't read it as "if p then q", especially the second part of the first sentence, that is: “F(x) is true if and only if the logical sentence that corresponds to the number x implies M.” and the whole part of the second sentence.
how should I read these sentences when there is the word implies?
I hope I explained it clearly.

Comment: "if p then q" also means "p implies q"

Comment: oh okay, thanks. so how should I read it in this situation mentioned? the sentence in such a fashion that I don't get it in the normal way.

Comment: "If the logical sentence that corresponds to the number x is true, then M."

Answer (score 1):

In general,

> "the logical sentence that corresponds to the number x"

is wrong : "the number x" is not a *sentence*.

**x** is a number and also **|x|** is. Thus, from a formal point of view, **|x|** is a *term* (i.e. a name).

The sentence is **F(x) = |x|**, and thus, **F** is not a *predicate* but a *function* symbol : this means that **F(x)** is also a *term*.

In conclusion, we have a first *sentence* of form **a=b** and a second sentence **M** and the expression :

> **F(x) = |x| → M**

is of form : "if p then q".

---

If instead the context is that of [Löb's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6b%27s_theorem), we have to be careful about the syntax of the formula : **F(x)** can be a predicate (or formula with a free variable) and thus we can correctly use **F(x) ≡ A** to write a sentence, but if **x** is a variable, then **|x|** is not a sentence.